# JSON Animation exported as Video mpeg

Tags: node.js, animation, video, ffmpeg, bodymovin

I have a json animation created in AfterEffects, exported with BodyMovin.
https://github.com/bodymovin/bodymovin

Is there any way to take this json file and programmatically transform it in to a video? Basically I am trying to create a JibJab style video, where a user can input a photo of their face and our app will take that face and place it over an animation. I need to transform that animation into a video file that can be saved to the user's phone. Maybe with ffmpeg?

Comment: Not availability such tools in public access, is main reason why jibjab can be paid service. If anyone can use any free tools to make similar video, nobody will pay. And nobody will pay to you, for your new service.

Comment: I appreciate the input @bukkojot but by that logic, nothing should be open source. Weird comment to write on StackOverflow, a platform all about helping other programmers, a good portion of who I'm sure are working on open source projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find free public face tracking software using the Microsoft Face Detection API.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-face-detection-app-with-react-native--cms-26491

We were also able to take individual images, and utilize ffmpeg to generate a video / gift from those images. We went our media up to S3 and utilized an AWS Lambda function to transform media upon upload. It didn't look great, but it kind of worked!

https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg